# Using search and update cursors for random number generation in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor, random

I am having some trouble getting a search cursor to return a value for each record. The purpose of my code is to scan through a list of records in a field (FieldA) and based on those values populate a second field (FieldB) with a random number between 1 and the value in FieldA. FieldA contains numeric values which vary depending on their association. My code is as follows:

```
CursorA = arcpy.SearchCursor(FC)
for row in cursorA:
    rowcount =(row.getValue("FieldA"))
    row = cursorA.next()
    cursorB = arcpy.UpdateCursor(FC, "FieldB") 
    for rowB in cursorB:
        rowB[0] = randint(1, rowcount)
        cursorB.updateRow(rowB)
```

When I run the code it appears as though the searchcursor locates the value of the last record in FieldA and uses that value as the highest value in the random sequence. I could be wrong on this however, and it could be related to improper coding on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This attached script shows the approach I would take.  The main operator here is the UpdateCursor itself.  You can see that I included both fields within one UpdateCursor. In the UpdateCursor, this translates to:

```
row[0] = 'FieldA'
row[1] = 'FieldB'
```

Then simply use these rows to do the heavy lifting for you:

```
rnumber = randint(1, row[0])
```

---

```
import arcpy, random
from random import *

fc = r'C:\path\to\fc'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['FieldA','FieldB']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        rnumber = randint(1, row[0])
        print rnumber
        row[1] = rnumber
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```